# Detecting MouseUp or dragging session "willEnd" on NSDraggingSession in Cocoa OSX

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nspasteboard

I've got an app where I'm allowing items to be dragged between NSTableViews.  When the drag leaves the table, the table closes around the starting location of the removed cell.

When a user lets go of an item and the drag will be cancelled, I'd like to animate TableCellView's starting location opening back up *at the same time* as the dragItem is being returned to the list, so that it looks like the tableView is "opening back up" to receive the cancelled item.

I'm having trouble detecting the moment that the user releases the mouse and the event is cancelled.  Both "draggingEnded" and "draggingSession( endedAt )" fire *after* the animation has completed.  Does anyone have any idea how to capture the "mouseUp" moment of the cancellation?